# How to insert stored procedure resultset into Temp table and query it

Tags: sap-ase, sybase-ase15

I am trying to insert the data into temp table from stored procedure. For instance

```sql
Insert into TempTable
EXEC dbo.MyProcedure(CustomerID)
```

In SQL Server it worked fine but in Sybase ASE 16 it gives me error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.

Can you advice is it possible or a workaround?

Comment: `insert/exec` is not supported in Sybase/SAP ASE; two options I can think of ... code the proc to insert directly into the temp table (either hardcoded temp table name or possibly pass temp table name to proc, have proc create/execute a dynamic `insert` statement) ... use `create existing table` to map a proxy table to the output from the stored proc, then run `insert temptable/select from proxytable`